# Typescript error when an object literal has functions

Tags: typescript

Here's the code:

```
function id<T>(x: T) {
    return x
}

const keys: string[] = []

const obj1 = Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [
    k, 
    {test() {}} // OK
]))

const obj2 = Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [
    k, 
    id({test() {}}) // Error
]))

const obj3 = Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [
    k, 
    id({test: new Date()}) // OK
]))
```

I have no idea why typescript gives this error:

```
Argument of type '{ test(): void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ test(): void; }'.
```

It seems that only functions in object literal cause this error.

The `id` function here is just for demo. Actual function has this signature:

`<T>(x: T) => T & SomeExtraFields`

Typescript version: 4.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu have sevaral ways to handle it:

**First:**

If you use reference instead of literal type, it works as expected:

```js
const id = <T,>(x: T): T => x

const keys: string[] = []

const iter = keys.map(k => [
    k,
    id({ test() { } }) // ok
])

const obj2 = Object.fromEntries(iter)
```

OR:

```js
const idResult = id({ test() { } })
const obj2 = Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [
    k,
    idResult
]))
```

**Second**

Let's try to use arrow function as property instead of method:

```js
const obj2 = Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [
    k,
    id({ test: () => { } }) // ok
]))
```

Strange behavior, is not it?

Let's  take a look on `Object.fromEntries` signature:

```js
fromEntries<T = any>(entries: Iterable<readonly [PropertyKey, T]>): { [k: string]: T };
```

So, TS tries to infer `T` generic type. In our case it is `ReturnType` of `id function`.

But for some reason, TS is unable to do it.

**Third:**

In order to help TS to infer the type, you can provide explicit generic argument for `Array.prototype.map`

```js
const obj2 = Object.fromEntries(
  keys.map<[string, { test(): void }]>((k) => [k, id({ test() {} })])
);
```

**Fourth**

You can also handle it without any explicit generic arguments.

You can just add constraint to `T` generic in your `id` function definition.

```js
interface Method {
  (): void;
}
const id = <T extends { [prop: string]: Method }>(x: T) => x;

const keys: string[] = [];

const obj2 = Object.fromEntries(keys.map((k) => [k, id({ test() {} })])); // ok


/////////////////////////

type ArrowProp = () => any;
const id = <T extends { [prop: string]: ArrowProp }>(x: T) => x;

const keys: string[] = [];

const obj2 = Object.fromEntries(keys.map((k) => [k, id({ test() {} })]));
```

**Fifth**

You can even use second generic to help TS to infer the type

```js
const id = <Prop, T extends Record<string, Prop>>(x: T) => x;
// OR
const id = <T extends object>(x: T) => x;


const keys: string[] = [];

const obj2 = Object.fromEntries(keys.map((k) => [k, id({ test() {} })]));
```

Unfortunately, I'm unable to explain why TS can't infer method property without any workarounds

Comment: Maybe that's a bug. By the way, in your second example if an arrow function takes any arguments, then the error shows again. I will use explicit generic type then. Sadly, because I love auto type inference.

Comment: Yep, it might be some inconcistency betwee method type an property with arrow function. Will you raise an issue on github? I can raise as well

Comment: I would be grateful if you could do this

Comment: @dhmk083 here https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43948 you have a link, hence you can track the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try it now.

```
function id<T>(x: T): T {
   return x
}

const keys: string[] = []

const obj1 = Object.entries(keys.map(k => [
    k,
    { test() { } } // OK
]))

const obj2 = Object.entries(keys.map(k => [
    k,
    id({ test() { } }) // Ok
]))

const obj3 = Object.entries(keys.map(k => [
    k,
    id({ test: new Date() }) // OK
]))
```